# Which date must I write on my visa application?

Tags: international-travel, schengen-visas, zimbabwean-citizens

I want to know which date I am supposed to write from Zimbabwe on my Schengen visa application for Germany.

Is it the one I am  leaving or the one I am arriving ? For example I am  travelling on the 30th of November and arriving on the 1st of December

Comment: Do we get to know where?

Comment: What visa application?  What does the actual question/field say?  Is it labeled just "date" or "date of ____"?

Answer (score 2):

The visa application dates are the dates of your planned departure and arrival. In the Schengen application form, there are a few fields similar:

- Field 25, "Duration of stay". This is how long your plan to stay in the Schengen area; so if you are applying to Germany, plan to visit Germany for 3 days, then France for 2 days - you would put 5 here.
- Field 30, "Date of arrival". This is when you will arrive at the border check-point (the immigration counter) or more practically speaking the airport where you will enter the Schengen zone.
- Field 31, "Date of departure". This is when you plan on leaving the Schengen zone; it doesn't have to be from the country where you entered the zone. You could enter from Frankfurt, and then exit from Paris.